# "of the following" vs "from the following"

Tags: word-choice

In the context of a website form, a user is required to use at least three of four listed character types in his or her password. Which is correct:

1)

```
Your password must contain three of the following: 
- Uppercase letters 
- Lowercase letters
- Numerals
- Non-alphanumeric characters
```

2)

```
Your password must contain three from the following: 
- Uppercase letters 
- Lowercase letters
- Numerals
- Non-alphanumeric characters
```

Comment: Three of the following makes more sense, because saying "three from the following" means that you have to pick three items - like a multiple choice question.

Comment: I don't think that makes very much difference. But from the way both are worded there is a bigger problem, I believe.  The first time I read it I thought it meant three of/from the following meant three characters from each.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Thanks for your input. The requirement is that the user must "pick" three unique "items" from a list of four.

Comment: @awesome: Exactly! So the first example tells you that in your password, you should have at least three from the list of uppercase letters; lowercase letters; numerals; non-alphanumeric characters. The second, though tells that you password must have at least three of the phrases "Uppercase letters; Lowercase letters; Numerals; Non-alphanumeric characters".

Comment: @WS2 Thanks. I agree—not much difference. Yes, the wording seems a bit confusing, but I'm constrained by the approved specs provided to me. However, I'm curious about which is more correct or even which is more acceptable.

Comment: You could replace it with "Your password must be hard to remember"

Comment: Does the user need to input three characters, or three characters from each of the types of character? The instruction is unclear.

Comment: It might help if it said 'Your password must contain characters from any three of the following'.

Comment: @Oldcat That would be way too practical.

Comment: @stib To create a valid password, the user must incorporate at least three different characters, each from a different character type of the listed four. This password requirement is to support a Microsoft API: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I think it would help to rephrase the instructions. Alas, I had approved specs dropped on my desk that I'm expected to implement. I didn't want to make a big deal about it, but personally I was interested in what others thought. Thanks for your input on this matter.

Comment: @TravisRodman RainbowT Thanks for the answers! The question came down to which of the two words, "of" and "from", was the more appropriate within context without changing the sentence structure. It would've been nice if an english teacher had weighed in with some formal usage cites, but I think we can sleep well having reached consensus on our own…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest "Of the Following", since these are listed as discreet items. If the options were presented as a set, say, "Your password must contain three from the following set: {upper case letters, lower case letters, numerals, non-alphabetic characters}", then I would use "from". The use of "from" implies a single entity/set, "of" implies a selection from a loose affiliation of entities.

Answer (score 0):

In colloquial terms, "of the following" sounds somewhat better and simpler than "from the following" which could easily be misinterpreted because it sounds awkward. That's just my two cents.